# Mount usb to serial adapter CANBUS and can-utils ubuntu?

Tags: usb, serial-port, can

I have this [adapter](http://www.jumo.de/products/pressure/402056/jumo-cantrans-p---pressure-transmitter-with-canopen-output-402056.html) and I'm trying desperately to mount it in Ubuntu so I can use `can-utils` to monitor the device but I'm failing.

I'm trying to communicate with a serial to the can-bus adapter in 14.04 with can-utils
this is the [canopen device I'm trying to get at](http://www.jumo.de/products/pressure/402056/jumo-cantrans-p---pressure-transmitter-with-canopen-output-402056.html) and [this is the adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FFZ8L24) I'm using

`dmesg`:

```
[ 4316.555254] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 4316.572534] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523
[ 4316.572541] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 4316.572545] usb 3-3: Product: USB2.0-Serial
[ 4316.573058] ch341 3-3:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[ 4316.574083] usb 3-3: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 4836.845113] CAN device driver interface
[ 5389.346203] can: broadcast manager protocol (rev 20120528 t)
[ 5570.910652] systemd-hostnamed[23407]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
```

That is dmesg output
for the device

Which I think is the device.

`lsusb` gives me:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter
```

I've managed to mount it to slcan0 
like so:

```
sudo slcand -o -s6 -t hw -S 3000000 /dev/ttyUSB2

ip link set up slcan0
```

IP link then gives me:

```
6: slcan1: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10
    link/can
```

No matter what I then throw it via can-send I can't get a response back...

Comment: `> [ 4316.574083] usb 3-3: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB1` and `> sudo slcand -o -s6 -t hw -S 3000000 /dev/ttyUSB2` doesn't seem to match?

Comment: Does the data flow at the bus physically? Watched it at Oscilloscope?

Comment: no nothing seems to output from anywhere....

Comment: Did you terminate bus properly? CAN bus uses terminating resistors. Without them doesn't work.

Comment: I assumed the adapter terminated the connection it's self: http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00FFZ8L24/?tag=stackoverfl08-20

Comment: How about ttyUSB1 versus ttyUSB2 above? Advice: make sure you understand how the device is to be terminated - you may well stumble on it now and later otherwise. It obviously reads "120ohm" on the label, there also seems to be a led beside the connector, close to that... whatever that means.

Comment: the ttyusb1/2 is a type on my part I've tried to connect it quite a few times...

Comment: @vimes1984, USB adapter supports max baud of 1M and Transmitter supports between 20K & 1M. The command you mentioned was with 3M baud. Try using a lower baud 1M (`-S 1000000`) or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a very old thread. But it is still unanswered and while I was searching for a solution I stumbled upon this thread.

The solution to this problem is that slcand does not support this interface.
To use it anyway a mapper between the interface and socket can must be used. 
This adapter can be found at https://github.com/alexmohr/usb-can

After install just run `usbcan -s 500000 -d /dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: I have `Ubuntu 18.04` installed and using CANBUS Analyzer. I installed the software you mentioned but I don't know why this canbus analyzer is not mounted as a `tty` device. `lsusb` gives me the following content for the device.


`Bus 003 Device 022: ID 0471:1200 Philips (or NXP) `

Do you have any idea how to solve the issue and use the adapter?

Comment: Your device is not supported, as I've already commented on the issue you've opened. Please use the issue for further communication.